# On demand paging in ext.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, extjs, ext.net

I have a store with more than a thousand rows.
When I bring to memory, 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

How the best way to do on demand paging using ext.net?

I do know how to bring the rows on demand from the databse, but I don't know how to do with the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PagedList. It's a nuget package with many good examples out there to control pagination (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList)

You modify your view to use the pagedlist model

```
    @using PagedList.Mvc;

    @model PagedList.IPagedList<WDCWebStore.ViewModels.VideoListViewModel>
```

And use the controller to return the pagedlist

```
    return View(viewModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

with the appropriate using
                using PagedList;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the paging feature of the Ext.NET GridPanel. 
It is explained in detail in [Ext.NET examples](http://examples.ext.net)